# OpenTK projection Moving and Scrolling camera

Tags: c#, opengl, 2d, opentk

I am writing graphical 2d editor and i am using OpenTK as rendering engine.
I wandering how could it possible to move and scroll the camera with the mouse to look like it is done in Photoshop.

Here is the code i have for now.

```
 GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
 GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
 GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
```

...

```
 GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
 GL.LoadIdentity(); 
 GL.Viewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
```

...

```
///Part od drawing function
            ClassNodeField nField = NodeFieldsManager.GetByID(ID);

            int Rows    = 4000 / 128 + 1;
            int Columns = 4000 / 128 + 1;


            GL.ClearColor(Color.Silver); 
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            GL.Color3(200f, 200f, 200f);

            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);


            for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(4000,     128 * i, 0);
                GL.Vertex3(4000,     128 * i, 0);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < Columns; i++)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(128 * i, 4000, 0);
                GL.Vertex3(128 * i, 4000, 0);
            }

            GL.End();
/// end part of drawing function
```

it is working fine a have the field 4000 by 4000 pixels for tests. I am planing to use 45000 by 45000. And now i need to navigate across this field and scroling with mouse wheel.
Help me with that what should i call from OpenTK to move my camera and scroll it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand openGL enough, there is no call to move the camera. As a result, you create a transformation matrix that does all the work for you. You should look into a world matrix.

Its a little mind bending for certain, so I will try to simplify it for you. Since openGL doesn't allow the camera to be moved (technically, there is no camera), have to move the world. You can think of it as moving a slide under a microscope, you can't move the microscope  for the sake of the slide. I haven't used OpenTK directly, but I have used Monogame which uses OpenTK.

So there are 2 options before you, 1) try to convert this call to work with OpenTK:

```
Matrix.CreateTranslation(location.x, location.y, 0f)
```

where location refers to the center of where you want to look. The other option, is to review any relevant documentation about openGL and OpenTK.

Comment: The relevant call in OpenTK would be: `Matrix4.CreateTranslation(location.x, location.y, 0.0f)`.

Comment: nothing happend.  With calling this functions. Where should i call it?

Comment: @AlexeyGapon That function only creates the matrix. Odds are you didn't use it after that. [This tutorial](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/basic-matrices) hits the nail on the head with regards to what the matrix does and the flow you will need to implement. As to where to implement it? In the update, but not the draw portion of your program. Also, you may want to read up on 3D game cameras. Just remember that the difference between 3D and 2D now is that 2D has all the depths set to the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Ok  thanks to everyone i solved this task.
The triangle always moves with the mouse cursor - but i think it i not a problem to make it only when the button is pressed (with two variables of old translate and new translate).

```
/*--------------------------------Program.cs------------------------------*/
    //Program.cs
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace OpenTK_OrthoCamera
    {
        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
        }
    }


/*--------------------------------Form1.Designer.cs------------------------*/
    namespace OpenTK_OrthoCamera
    {
        partial class Form1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                if (disposing && (components != null))
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }

            #region Windows Form Designer generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.glControl1 = new OpenTK.GLControl();
                this.SuspendLayout();
                // 
                // glControl1
                // 
                this.glControl1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                this.glControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                this.glControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
                this.glControl1.Name = "glControl1";
                this.glControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(892, 521);
                this.glControl1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.glControl1.VSync = false;
                this.glControl1.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.glControl1_Load);
                this.glControl1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.glControl1_Paint);
                this.glControl1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.glControl1_MouseMove);
                this.glControl1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.glControl1_Resize);
                this.glControl1.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.OnMouseWheel);
                // 
                // Form1
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(916, 545);
                this.Controls.Add(this.glControl1);
                this.Name = "Form1";
                this.Text = "Form1";
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }


            #endregion

            private OpenTK.GLControl glControl1;
        }
    }

/*--------------------------------Form1.cs-------------------------------*/
    using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace OpenTK_OrthoCamera
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            bool loaded = false;

            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            float z = 0;


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Loads Control
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void glControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                loaded = true;
                GL.ClearColor(Color.SkyBlue); // Yey! .NET Colors can be used directly!

                SetupViewport();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Setup the Viewport
            /// </summary>
            private void SetupViewport()
            {

                GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
                GL.LoadIdentity();            

                int w = glControl1.Width;
                int h = glControl1.Height;

                float orthoW = w * (z + 1);
                float orthoH = h * (z + 1);

                GL.Ortho(0, orthoW, 0, orthoH, -1, 1); // Bottom-left corner pixel has coordinate (0, 0)
                GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h); // Use all of the glControl painting area
            }



            /// <summary>
            /// Calculate Translation of  (X, Y, Z) - according to mouse input
            /// </summary>
            private void SetupCursorXYZ()
            {
                x =   PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X  * (z + 1);
                y = (-PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y + glControl1.Height) * (z + 1); 
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// We need to setup each time our viewport and Ortho.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void glControl1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!loaded)
                    return;

                SetupViewport();
            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Paint The control.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!loaded) // Play nice
                    return;

                GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

                GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
                GL.LoadIdentity();

                GL.Translate(x, y, 0); // position triangle according to our x variable

                GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
                GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
                GL.Vertex2(10, 20);
                GL.Vertex2(100, 20);
                GL.Vertex2(100, 50);
                GL.End();

                glControl1.SwapBuffers();

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// The triangle will always move with the cursor. 
            /// But is is not a problem to make it only if mousebutton pressed. 
            /// And do some simple ath with old Translation and new translation.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sender"></param>
            /// <param name="e"></param>
            private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                x = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X  * (z + 1);
                y = (-PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y + glControl1.Height) * (z + 1);

                SetupCursorXYZ();

                glControl1.Invalidate();
            }


            private void OnMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Delta > 0 && z > 0) z -= 0.5f;
                if (e.Delta < 0 && z < 5) z += 0.5f;

                SetupCursorXYZ();

                SetupViewport();
                glControl1.Invalidate();
            }

        }
    }
```

Try it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace  code

```
GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
GL.Vertex2(10, 20);
GL.Vertex2(100, 20);
GL.Vertex2(100, 50);
GL.End();
```

with this one

```
 GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);

            for (int i = -20; i < 20; i++)
                for (int j = -20; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    GL.Vertex2(10 + i * 200 , 20 + j *200);
                    GL.Vertex2(100 + i * 200, 20 + j * 200);
                    GL.Vertex2(100 + i * 200, 50 + j * 200);
                }
            GL.End();
```

and you will see how it works more clearly: